# Flutter mixin with abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I have a mixin and abstract class extends StatefulWidget. I wanna add my mixin to abstract class.

Mixin:

```
mixin MyMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {

 String translate(context,childKey)
{
var parentKey =  getParentLocalisationKey();
return  childKey+parentKey;
}

String getParentLocalisationKey();
 }
```

And abstract class:

```
 abstract class BaseState<Page extends BasePage> extends State<Page>
with WidgetsBindingObserver {
 }
```

How can i add mixin to abstract class? Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

It goes in the list after the `with`:

```dart
abstract class BaseState<Page extends BasePage> extends State<Page>
  with WidgetsBindingObserver, MyMixin<Page> {
}
```